# How to read from catalina.properties in log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

**My system configuration is:**
Tomcat 9.0.14 on Windows
Java 8
Spring Boot
log4j2

**In my catalina.properties, I have the following property defined:**

```
server_log_root=D:/Bharath/Projects/Logs
```

**In my log4j2.xml file, I am trying to access the above property as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_HOME">${sys:server_log_root}</Property>
        <Property name="CONVERSION_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} tId=%X{TRANSACTION_ID} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE_APPENDER" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${CONVERSION_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>

        <File name="API_SERVICES_FILE_APPENDER" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/api_services_log.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${CONVERSION_PATTERN}" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE_APPENDER" level="debug"/>
        </Root>

        <Logger name="API_SERVICES_FILE_LOGGER" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="API_SERVICES_FILE_APPENDER" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Upon running my application, the logs are not getting created in the folder (D:/Bharath/Projects/Logs).

I tried changing the folder path style from / to \ but no luck still.
**Also, I tried using the following but none worked:**

```
$${sys:server_log_root}
${env:server_log_root}
$${env:server_log_root}
${server_log_root}
$${server_log_root}
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,
Bharath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting the property as an environment variable inside "context.xml" (instead of catalina.properties)